# pptp vpn with certificate

Tags: vpn, pptp, certificates

I want to connect to a windows pptp vpn server which accepts only connections with a CA certficate.

From windows im able to do it easily (since its windows of course and native supported)
but from my ubuntu 10.04 im not able to setup the vpn to authenticate using a certificate.

any help?

thanks

Comment: no reply..i guess there is no way to do it...

Comment: There might be, maybe if you do a couple of things like updating the system to the latest version so users with that version can try to give you an answer and also adding more information to the question. I would suggest creating a new question explaining in details the problem (And of course an updated Ubuntu version). That will certainly pull many readers to your question.